# Layout/text appear larger in live site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've developed a wordpress theme on my local machine using apache, when I upload it to the internet hosting server the layout looks larger however the layout still looks fine.It's kind of like it's expanded everything 5%.

I'm viewing the site in firefox only on my local enviroment and on the live site.

When I switch between the two environments it still appears larger on the live site.

If I'm using Win7 and the internet host is using linux will that affect the layout?

My conatainer div's are set in px and I've also set the default font-size to 14px.

Comment: Inspect the text with firebug and verify font sizes are actually the same.

Comment: ok will do, although  it seems to expand the container aswell which is set to px.

Comment: I installed FireFox, the wrapper is 940px width and 20px padding.I view both in the same browser, but my local machine looks thinner still. I'm going to screenshot both screens (local & live Enviroment) and paste them into Photoshop to measure what is the accurate one. I'm following the box model so I'm guuessing the total width should be 940+20+20=980px.Sooooo confused right now lol.

Comment: Could it be that my local apache server is not reading the mime type correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a different browser to test in?

Have you tried pressing Ctrl+Zero to reset the zoom level?

Comment: Not as yet, but I will also give that a shot. Cheers

Comment: +1 for the zoom level. Browsers store this on a site-by-site basis and it's easy to trigger accidentally but not so easy to restore.